# Ubuntu 14.04 does not autoboot

Tags: boot, grub2

My Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't autoboot, I've to manually select the default grub item.

My /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I tried to add this line:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
```

or

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

and make a sudo update-grub nothing happens.

I also tried to edit /etc/grub.d/00_header overwritting the make_timeout() function changing timeout=-1 with timeout=1, but nope :(

Finally I tried to restore the defaults with dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc, and nothing.

Any idea?

Comment: What means `$GRUP_TIMEOUT`? Did you mean `$GRUB_TIMEOUT`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment all `GRUB_HIDDEN`. I would also change `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR` to something static, like `Debian`.

Comment: I don't see how changing *GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR* will affect boot.

Answer (score 0):

Just uncomment `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and do a `sudo update-grub`. Commenting out `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` prevents GRUB from being automatically hidden.